# Figure out proper match regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am relatively new to programming.  I am currently learning Perl and I ran into a logical problem that’s preventing me from finishing the script correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!  Thank you in advance for your useful insights!

The bulk of the program has already been written, it is the last step that's giving me a headache.

I have a variable `$RNA`, which gets sequences of nucleotides (`acgu`) in any order.  For example:

```
$RNA = agcuaggaaggguuuugauag
```

and so on.

I already created a hash where every 3 nucleotide character or codon (e.g uga) is assigned to a defined amino acid.  E.g:

```
% my AminoAcid   = (
  ggg => "G",
  ...
);
```

What I want to do is to print the defined amino acids (the letters in upper case) corresponding to the codons in the hash whenever it reads the START CODON `aug` within the `$RNA` strings and to *stop* printing the defined amino acids in the hash whenever it reads the STOP CODON `uga`.

For example: Suppose `$RNA = aaaaugcccgggugaccccccccc`. The program should print the corresponding amino acids starting for (`aug`) and stop when it reads the stop codon (`uga`) within the string.

NOTE: It should ignore the first three `aaa` before it reads the START codon (`aug`) and the `ccccccccccccc` after it reads the stop codon (`uga`) and repeat the same process if it sees the start codon `aug` again anywhere in the string.

I have tried multiple ideas and none of them came even close to depicting the proper way of writing the code for that last part.  I probably don't fully get the logic behind it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: does `aug` have to be at an index divisible by 3 or can it just appear anywhere?

Comment: can you post the code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work, put the logic in a Code group `(?{})`

**Mod for mutilpe lines**
Note - if there should ever need to be a re-alignment (by 3's) let me know.
As of now the alignment is 3 non-whitespace + optional whitespace(s), repeat.
This will consume the line breaks while maintaining the 3 boundry - which I
assume is important.

Perl code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %AminoAcid   = (
   aug => "Start codon",
   ccc => "C",
   ggg => "G",
   uuu => "U"
);

my $RNA = '
aaaaugcccgggugacccgggcccgggcccaaaauguuugggcccugacccgggccccccaugccc
gggugacccgggcccgggcccaaaauguuugggcccugacccgggcccccc
aaaaugcccgggugacccgggcccgggcccaaaauguuugggcccugacccgggcccccc
aaaaugcccgggugacccgggcccgggcccaaaauguuugggcccugacccgggcccccc
';
my $on = 0;

$RNA =~ /
     (?:
          ( \S\S\S ) \s*
          (?{
               if ( $^N eq 'aug' ){ $on = 1; print "\n"; }
               elsif ( $^N eq 'uga' ) { $on = 0; }
               if ( $on ) {
                  exists $AminoAcid{ $^N } ?
                    print $AminoAcid{ $^N } :
                    print "[key not found-> '$^N']";
               }
          })
     )+
   /x;
```

Output

```
Start codonCG
Start codonUGC
Start codonCG
Start codonUGC
Start codonCG
Start codonUGC
Start codonCG
Start codonUGC
```

Comment: The code above will not print blank lines. Did you copy'n'paste the entire code ? Yep, there is only one `print "\n"` in the code, since the `$on` is set in this block, it always prints `\n`+`$AminoAcid{ $^N }` where `$^N` is the contents of the last capture buffer, and is the 'key' to that hash value. If the key does not exist, it is auto-created with a blank value. I'll put some error check in for you.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, tweaked for multiple lines, and added a bit of error check for the key existence.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with this:

```
my $rna = "aaaaugcccgggugaccccccccc";
my %aminoAcidMap = ( ggg => "G", ccc => "C" );
```

The first step is to extract the relevant part between `aug` and `uga`:

```
$rna =~ /aug((?:[acgu]{3})*?)uga/ or die;
my $pattern = $1;
```

This assumes that `aug` can appear anywhere in the string. Also, it ensures if doesn't stop at `uga` if it spans two codons.

If you require the start codon to be at an index in the string that is divisible by 3, you can do this instead:

```
$rna =~ /^(?:[acgu]{3})*?aug((?:[acgu]{3})*?)uga/ or die;
my $pattern = $1;
```

At this point, `$pattern` will contain the part between `aug` and `uga`.

Now, to do the mapping, you can do:

```
my $aminoAcids = $pattern =~ s/[acgu]{3}/$aminoAcidMap{$&}/ger;
```

This will replace each codon with the value from the hash.

If you pack everything into a sub, you get:

```
sub getAminoAcids {
    local ($_) = @_;
    /aug((?:[acgu]{3})*?)uga/ or return "";
    $1 =~ s/[acgu]{3}/$aminoAcidMap{$&}/ger;
}
```

Comment: Hello Lucas, a MILLION thanks!!!!  I greatly appreciate your help! The only block I don't quite follow is the "sub" block. Would you mind explaining to me what exactly you did? For instance, which statement STOP doing the translation of codon to the Amino Acids when it reads the STOP Codon? Thank you in advance!!  Also, pardon my ignorance, is it there a simpler way to accomplish the same thing? I tried the for, while and the until loops. Since, I am not an expert, I figured  might have misused them.  Thank you again!

Comment: @Dimitri the `sub` is a subroutine/function, it's for code reuse. For instance: `print getAminoAcids "aaaaugcccgggugaccccccccc";` To make it I just took the other code from the answer, got rid of temporary variables and put it all together. The *stop* codon is read by the regular expression (the one starting with `/aug`) - see [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more details. And yes, I didn't really go for the *simple to understand* way, I went for the *most compact, most efficient* way (getting the job done in 3 lines of code). Granted, Perl isn't the easiest language to learn.

Answer (score 0):

@lucas-trzesniewski's sub is great and very compact, but it has some drawbacks: it doesn't handle interspersed hard returns, only finds the first protein, does not print the first Methionine, and modifies $_/$1 with an implicit return (which is something that I try to avoid).  So here's an improvement.  Note, I have a very tricked-out translation script of my own which handles a lot more cases (e.g. overlapping reading frames, ambiguous nucleotides, RNA fragments, alternate start codons, multiple stop codons, etc), but if you just want something simple for limited cases, here's a modified version of @lucas-trzesniewski's sub that addresses those issues:

```
sub getAminoAcids
  {
    my $mrna = @_;
    $mrna =~ s/\s+//sg;
    $mrna = lc($mrna);
    my @proteins = ();
    while($mrna =~ /(aug(?:[acgu]{3})*?)uga/g)
      {
        $cds = $1;
        push(@proteins,"");
        while($cds =~ /(...)/g)
          {$proteins[-1] .= $aminoAcidMap{$1}}
      }
    return(@proteins);
  }
```

This assumes you don't want to print a stop character in your protein string.  It also could have extras like error-checking.